# Python object that evaluates to True when compared

Tags: python, boolean, boolean-expression

I need a Python object that always evaluates to `True` when it is compared to. For example, if this object was called `TRUE`, then:

```
TRUE == 10
TRUE == False
TRUE == True
TRUE == "hello"
TRUE == list()
```

Is there a built-in Python object for this?

Note I'm asking for a built-in object. If I'm going to be checking whether `x == y` hundreds of times, with `y` changing, and `x` being set and unset, for those instances when it is unset, I want `x == y` to evaluate to `True`. (And when `x` is set, I want an actual comparison operation to be performed)

I figure python might have an optimized built in object for this.

Comment: No; why would there be? You can easily roll your own by implementing `__eq__`.

Comment: just ouf of curiosity, why would you want to do that?

Comment: If you want an expression that always evaluates to `True`, why not just use `True`?

Comment: @JulienSpronck: It's for some research code I'm writing. The `TRUE` object will eventually be replaced by another instance of another object, so one way to advert this would be replacing `TRUE` with `None` and checking whether `x is None`. But if you do this check a large number of times, you lose performance.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: If you compare `True` with any other object, this yields `False`, not `True`

Comment: @hlin117 I think Tigerhawk meant why not replace `x == y` with `True` because he is referring to the whole __expression__.

Comment: I suspect `==` isn't the predicate you should really be using here.

Comment: As @jake said, I meant replacing the whole expression with `True`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class TRUE(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True
# no reason to have more that one instance (I think?)
TRUE = TRUE()

print(TRUE == 10)
print(TRUE == False)
print(TRUE == True)
print(TRUE == "hello")
print(TRUE == list())
```

Addendum:
As others have noted, there doesn't seem to be an obvious use for `TRUE`. I can't really think of one. Though I can imagine a use for a similar object:

```
class MIN(object):
    def __lt__(self, other): return True
    def __le__(self, other): return True
    def __gt__(self, other): return False
    def __ge__(self, other): return False
    def __eq__(self, other): return False
MIN = MIN()
```

If I was trying to test a min heap, `MIN` would always be at the top. For a max heap it would always be at the bottom. This would be regardless of the type of the elements in the queue.

Comment: Change the object name to something other than the class name.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I did that intentionally. there's no reason to have more than one instance.

Answer (score 0):

*I need a python object that always evaluates to True when it is compared to.*

No, you don't. Proof: Suppose that such value TRUE exists. Then the expression `TRUE == x` is equivalent to `True` for all x. Thus the entire expression can be replaced with `True`.

It is bad practice to overload `__eq__` to make it simply return `True`.

If you want an expression that always evaluates to True for a certain object, maybe this would be a better approach:

```
class AlwaysTrue():
    pass

l = [1,2,3,4,5,AlwaysTrue(),7,8,AlwaysTrue()]

search_value = 6
for x in l:
    if x == search_value or isinstance(x, AlwaysTrue):
        print('Value found!')
        break
```

Notice that 6 is not in the list, but this still prints 'Value found!'

Comment: Yeah ... this question is really odd.

Comment: Your proof assumes that the expression contains the literal `TRUE`. But what if he's comparing `x == y`? I agree it's a strange request, but I can't say for sure something like this would never be useful.

Comment: @axblount I have added another suggestion with what I think would be a better practice.

Comment: Here's an example where `TRUE` would be useful: `assert mytuple == (TRUE, 2)` here, assert is True if `mytuple` has length 2 and the last entry is a `2`. In my opinion `assert mytuple == (TRUE, 2)` is more elegant than e.g. `len(mytuple)==2 and mytuple[-1]==2`, although I would rather call it "ANY" than "TRUE".

Answer (score 0):

You need to overload operators, but really what is the point of it?

```
class Custom:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True
```